# Make an element appear behind an element but is placed inside of it

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make an element appear behind the elements parent?

like so

```
<div style="background-color:blue;">
   blue
  <div style="margin:0 0 0 0 -10px;background-color:red;">red</div>
</div>
```

Having the blue div covering the red div, but having 10 pixels stick out to the left?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible using `position`:

```html
<div style="background-color:blue;position:relative;">
  blue
  <div style="background-color:red;position:relative;left:-10px;">red</div>
</div>
```

If you want both of them in the same line, then you need to put `top: 0;` and `position:absolute` too.

```html
<div style="background-color:blue;position:relative;">
  blue
  <div style="background-color:red;position:absolute;left:-10px;top:0;z-index:-1;">red</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by adding negative `z-index` to inner div. You have to note that this method works only if parent element doesn't have `z-index` value.

```css
div {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
.outer {
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
}
.inner {
  margin: 0 0 0 -10px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  blue
  <div class="inner">red</div>
</div>
```